# For data-type "Number" num.[[PrimitiveValue]] is giving error. Why?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, numbers

In JavaScript, `Object Class` is the center of all happenings regarding data-type. One of the children of `Object Class` is `Number Class`. On making or creating a variable of type `number` its `__proto__` will point to `Number Class` which then (via Prototypal Inheritance) makes a set of properties readily available to be used (eg: toExponential, toFixed, toString, etc.)

When I went through the whole list, I found at the end 2 more properties -- `__proto__` and `[[PrimitiveValue]]` Now, just like the other properties, these 2 must also be readily avialable. So, I tried ... Now, to my dissapointment out of all these properties, the last one *[[PrimitiveValue]]* is giving error on Usage! Now, my surprise is, if via *prototypal_Inheritance* all the other properties are available and give some result, then **what the heck is with this last property**? I am simply tring to access it **and ideally it should retrun me 0**. That's all, so why the error???

**Snippet:**

[image]

Comment: @bergi - can you still explain whether `[[ ... ]]` is -- property of `Number Class` or not?

Comment: No, it's not a property. It's an internal slot on the `Number.prototype` object. You cannot access it. Same for *[[prototype]]* - it's an internal slot, not a property, you have to access it through `Object.getPrototypeOf` (or the deprecated `.__proto__`)